# declaration of reference and pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, declaration

For example, if F is a reference to an integer, where the reference is not permitted to be pointed to a new object once it is initially pointed to one.

Can I write to declaration like: const int & F?

I am confused about reference and pointer, because they both represent the address of something, but we always write parameter use reference as: const & F, I understand that this is to reduce the copy and does not allow others to change it, but are there any other meanings? and why do we need "const" after a function declaration like: int F(int z) const; this const makes the return type const or everything in the function const?

One more example,

```
void F(int* p)
{
p+=3;
}

int z=8;
F(&z);
std::cout<<z<<std::endl;
```

What is the output for z since z is a reference, and I pass it as a pointer who points to an integer.Increasing p by 3 just makes the address different and does not change its value?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Which C++ book are you learning from?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit let's just hope Fred will come up with something more interesting ^^

Comment: "because they both represent the address of something..." No, a reference does not represent the address of something. It is an *alias* for something, and it can only refer to one thing.

Comment: Declarations are parsed from "inside out" or "right to left". So:

    const int &F

means a reference (modifiable one) to const int.
To declare a const reference to a modifiable int is considered an anachronism
and it looks like this:

    int & const F

Answer (score 3):

Just a first pass at some answers - if anything is unclear please comment and I'll try to elaborate.

```
int a = 3;
```

declares an integer, `a`, with the initial value 3, but you are allowed to change it. For example, later you can do

```
a = 5;   // (*)
```

and `a` will have the value 5. If you want to prevent this, you can instead write

```
const int a = 3;
```

which will make the assignment `(*)` illegal - the compiler will issue an error.

If you create a reference to an integer, you are basically creating an alias:

```
int& b = a;
```

, despite appearances, does not create a new integer `b`. Instead, it declares `b` as an alias for `a`. If `a` had the value 3 before, so will `b`, if you write `b = 6` and print the value of `a`, you will get 6 as well. Just as for `a`, you can make the assignment `b = 6` illegal by declaring it as const:

```
const int& b = a;
```

means that `b` is still an alias for `a`, but it will not be used to assign a different value to `a`. It will only be used to read the value of `a`. Note that `a` itself still may or may not be constant - if you declared it as non-`const` you can still write `a = 6` and `b` will also be `6`.

As for the question about the pointers: the snippet

```
void F(int* p) {
  p += 3;
}

int z = 8;
F(&z);
```

does not do what you expected. You pass the address of `z` into the function `F`, so inside `F`, the pointer `p` will point to `z`. However, what you are doing then, is adding `3` to the value of `p`, i.e. to the *address* that `p` points to. So you will change to pointer to point at some (semi)random memory address. Luckily, it's just a copy, and it will be discarded. What you probably *wanted* to do, is increment the value of the integer that `p` points *to*, which would be `*p += 3`. You could have prevented this mistake by making the argument a `int* const`, meaning: the value of `p` (i.e. address pointed to) cannot be changed, but the value it points to (i.e. the value of `z`, in this case) *can*. This would have made `*p += 3` legal but not the "erroneous" (unintended) `p += 3`. Other versions would be `const int* p` which would make `p += 3` legal but not `*p += 3`, and const int* const` which would have allowed neither.

Actually, the way you have written `F` is *dangerous*: suppose that you expand the function and later you write (correctly) `*p += 3`. You *think* that you are updating the value of `z` whose address you passed in, while *actually* you are updating the value of a more-or-less random memory address. In fact, when I tried compiling the following:

```
// WARNING WARNING WARNING
// DANGEROUS CODE - This will probably produce a segfault - don't run it!

void F(int* p) {
  p += 3;   // I thought I wrote *p += 3

  // ... Lots of other code in between, I forgot I accidentally changed p

  *p += 3;  // NOOOOOOOOOOO!
}

int main()
{
    int z=8;
    F(&z);

   std::cout << z;
   return 0;
}
```

I got a segmentation fault, because I'm writing at an address where I haven't allocated a variable (for all I know I could have just screwed up my boot sector).

Finally, about `const` *after* a function declaration: it makes the `this` pointer a `const` pointer - basically the compiler emits `const A* this` instead of just `A* this`. Conceptually, it states your intention that the function will not change the state of the class, which usually means it won't change any of the (internal) variables. For example, it would make the following code illegal:

```
class A {
  int a;

  void f() const {
    a = 3;  // f is const, so it cannot change a!
  }
};

A a;
a.f();
```

Of course, if the function returns something, this value can have its own type, for example

```
void f();
int f();
int& f();
const int f();
const int& f();
```

are functions that return nothing, a (copy of) an integer, a (reference to) an integer, a constant (copy of) an integer, and a constant reference of an integer. If in addition `f` is guaranteed not to change any class fields, you can also add `const` after the brackets:

```
void f() const;
int f() const;
int& f() const;
const int f() const;
const int& f() const;
```

Comment: This isn't really right about the `const` after a function.  The `const` after a function makes the `this` pointer a pointer to `const`; it means that you can't change non-mutable members (at least without a `const_cast`), but you can't return non-const references or pointers to them either; you can't call non-const member functions, and most importantly, if the function isn't `const`, you can't call it on a const object, or through a reference or a pointer to a const object.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKanze, is the reworded version better?

Comment: Somewhat.  Although the compiler doesn't emit any declaration for `this`.  But in the context of the OPs question, I thought the fact that `int& f() const;` wouldn't be legal (assuming that `f` returned a reference to a member) relevant.

Comment: Then what is the output for z if I use F(&z), cause this is one of my exam question, if the z's address is increased by 3, what is the output then?

Comment: You cannot "increase `z`'s address by 3". `z`'s address is what it is. You can make a pointer to `z`'s address, and increase that by 3, but then it will point at another address. Which one? There's no telling! IMO, the only contexts in which such things only slightly make sense is (a) when using arrays or (b) when you know exactly how your memory is used, such as in very low-level stuff or code that needs to be ridiculously efficient. And even when using arrays I would tend to avoid it and use `operator[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The way I remember the difference between references and pointers is that a reference must exist and the reference cannot change.

A pointer can be changed, and usually needs to be checked against NULL or tested to verify it points to a valid object.

Also, an object passed by reference can be treated syntactically like it was declared in the function.  Pointers must use deferencing syntax.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing things.

First of all `int z=8; F(&z);` here z IS NOT a reference.

So let me start with the basics:

when found in a type declaration the symbol `&` denotes a reference, but in any other context, the symbol `&` means address of.
Similar, in a type declaration `*` has the meaning of declaring a pointer, anywhere else it it the dereferencing operator, denoting you use the value at an address.

For instance:
`int *p` : p is a **pointer** of type int. 
`x = *p` : x is assigned **the value found at address** p.

`int &r = a` : r is **reference** of type int, and r refers the variable a. 
`p = &a` : p is assigned **the address of variable** a.

Another question you have: the const at the end of a function, like `int f(int x) const`. This can be used **only** on non-static class methods and specifies that the function does not modify the object. It has nothing to do with the return value.